# Do virtual machines need swap partitions?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, swapfile

I am running Ubuntu on my physical machine; and VirtualBox to run various virtual ones on top.

Most of the time, I was doing "straight forward" installations; but today I wanted to be "smart" and checked out the partitions that the fedora or ubuntu installers will create on my virtual disks.

And sure, when going for the defaults, some GBs of my virtual disks will be used as "swap space".

Now I am wondering: assuming that I have plenty of physical memory (so I can assign 6 or 8 GB to a VM) - is there any sense in dedicated swap space for a a virtual machine?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is [answered at ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/a/351176):

TL;DR: use swap: 1. avoids out of memory error, 2. guest OS is better at memory management

> Ignoring the fact that people are dealing with OS specific reasons I
>   have two reasons why it's a bad idea to not run with a swap
>   partition/file.
>
> 1. If you have 1.5 GB of RAM allocated to a VM with no space file/partition and it wants to use 1.5 GB + 1 MB it will report an out
>      of memory error. With the swap space it will be able to swap data out
>      of active memory and onto the disk.
> 2. The guest OS does a much better job of memory management than the host. This is why technology like memory ballooning exists because the
>      Host can make educated guesses on what memory isn't needed right now
>      but the guest knows at a much more intelligent level (this keeps OS
>      memory from being swapped out which could kill your performance).

Answer (score 4):

Swap partitions are used to free your physical memory when it goes out of space. In modern day machines, with plenty of memory, it depends on the type of applications you would be running. If you are planning to run such memory intensive programs like video editors, high end games or something of that sort, virtual memory or swap space is an asset. But if it is not the case then you are safe to avoid swap space, provided you have enough memory. But it is safe to have a fallback.

Answer (score 3):

That depends on what programs you are running on your host system along with the virtual machine, or what programs you are running within the virtual machine.

The only upper bound on memory that software can consume is the total memory (physical or virtual) available to it.   There are plenty of programs that require large amounts of memory when behaving normally, and plenty of circumstances that cause a program to consume large amounts of memory (e.g. loading of input files).   There are also plenty of faulty programs that unintentionally consume large amounts of memory.

You can often get an idea by examining requirements or recommendations (e.g. memory and drive space) of the programs you run.   Failing that, try it out.